# Can I set up custom time on SQL database or server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to test my database to check some operation that will be executed in intervals. / eg. making report at end of month/ 
Is there a way to setup database time to custom time? 
If not, is there a way to test it? and how it should looks like?

Comment: Do you want to rollback your DB to some point in time to build some reports and then turn back to the current time?

Comment: no, I would like to see if my procedures will be executed,

Comment: Change the logic to run at a different time, see if it happens.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I've done in the past to test things like this. Set it to run a minute or two from the current time (depending on how long it takes to setup). So if it's 8:28am... set it to run at 8:30am.